# Add the filename into header by removing the extension in multiple file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have text files with three columns shown below.

```
6:85406127 T:A 0.44 
6:85406139 T:C 0.00
6:85406165 C:G 0.33
```

I would like to add the filename before the extension in the third column.

My desired output is gonna be like:

```
CHR:POS REF:ALT Filename

6:85406127 T:A 0.44
6:85406139 T:C 0.0
6:85406165 C:G 0.33
```

Then I used this command:

```
for i in *.txt; do awk 'BEGIN{print "CHR:POS REF:ALT "${i%.*}"" {print}' $i ; done
```

But received this error message

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{print "CHR:POS REF:ALT "${i%.*}"" {print}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                ^ syntax error
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you are trying to use a shell variable inside an `awk` script. Since you have enclosed your `awk` script in single quotes (which _is_ the recommended way), shell variable expansion is disabled. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for how to pass shell variables to `awk` scripts.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks. I added as a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
for i in *.txt ; do awk -v fname="${i%.*}" 'NR == 1 { print  "CHR:POS"," ","REF:ALT"," ",fname,"\n" } 
               NR >=1 { print }' $i > "${i%.*}_header.txt" ; done
```

Comment: if you want this for multiple files, instead of using loop; use FelixJN answer but replace `NR` with `FNR`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the filename in `awk` use `FILENAME`, however the problem is, that this item is not loaded in the `BEGIN`-block, thus you will have to do it on the first record:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print "Header-Col1","Header-Col2",FILENAME}
     NR>=1 { print }' input_file
```

Add a newline after the header line (`"\n"`) if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do not want to include the extension of the filename in the header.

Comment: Based on your and  @AdminBee's answer  I used that command, and it worked! Thanks @Fiximan!  `for i in *.txt ; do awk 'NR == 1 { print  "CHR:POS",  "REF:ALT",  "'${i%.*}'" } NR >=1 { print }' $i > $i\_header ; done`

Comment: @FatmaA. May I still recommend that you don't interrupt the quoting of the `awk` script, and use a construct like `for i in *.txt; do awk -v fname="${i%.*}" 'NR==1{print "CHR:POS", "REF:ALT", fname} etc.' $i > $i\_header; done`.

Comment: @FatmaA. use string manipulation, e.g.: `sub(/\..*/,"",FILENAME) ; print FILENAME` (in this case assuming only one dot-character in filename, separating the suffix, otherwise the regex has to be more explicit)

Comment: @Fiximan Your first recommendation works very well. But I did not understand the second one. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @FatmaA. If the "first recommendation" you refer to is that which you ended up adding as solution to your question, it actually came from me - but you're welcome ;)

Comment: Sorry I did not notice it that the second is not from your @AdminBee. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @FatmaA. - I cannot follow. Which part do you need explained? The use of `FILENAME` or the string manipulation with `sub`?

Comment: Yes @Fiximan please

Comment: your command can be shorten to `awk 'NR == 1 { print "Header-Col1","Header-Col2",FILENAME} { print }' infile` or even `awk 'NR == 1 { print "Header-Col1","Header-Col2",FILENAME}1' infile`